# How can I use "perspective" to express "in my opinion"?

Tags: word-usage

Should I use "from my perspective", or "in my perspective" or "on my perspective?"
Can "standpoint" and "view" be used in the same way?

Comment: From my perspective and from where I stand; from my point of view; the way I see it.http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+my+perspective.       . From my perspective: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from+my+perspective%2C+on+my+perspective%2C+in+my+perspective&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20my%20perspective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20my%20perspective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20my%20perspective%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Yes, but that's redundant. Unless you're quoting some other authority, what comes from your mouth or pen is generally considered or understood to be your opinion/view/perspective/standpoint. Contrast: Speaking on behalf of other(s), Speaking as a definitive source.

Comment: @SrJoven You mean?

Comment: It's too long to discuss. "*From* my perspective/view/standpoint/point of view" is correct. If you'd like answers on the nuance of "From my perspective" in English Language and Usage as it relates to whether and when it's proper to use it, I figure that might be an interesting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use 'from my perspective', 'from my standpoint' or 'in my view'. I personally wouldn't use any of the other variations.